# Comparing two arrays of integers and returning the subscript (C)

Tags: c

(a newer version of my program is right in the end)

I need to create a program with a function that compares two arrays of integers and returns the subscript of the first place they differ.

I have to use a sentinel value to indicate the end of valid input, rather than EOF, as a file cannot have two end-of-files.

Example of my desired input and output for my program:

Input 1:

```
    3 4 5

    3 4 6
```

Output 1:

```
       2
```

Explanation: the third values of two arrays are different, so it prints the third subscript (counting as 0,1,2).

I looked over similar issues on stackoverflow. Many errors were fixed and now it lets me to compile a program, without giving me any errors or warnings. But it blinds me because I don't understand what exactly doesn't work.

My problem that I encounter:

- When I press *Enter* button after the first value, the program stops working.

I assume my tableDiff function is wrong, however I copied it from teacher's notes. Unless I made a typo, there shouldn't be any difference.

> Here is my submitted version:

```
/*
* A simple program to sort numbers in the correct order                             
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10 //max elements in array
#define SENTINEL -999 //indicate the end of valid input

int main () {
    int tableFill(int a[], int max);
    int tableDiff (const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m);
    void tablePrint (const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m);

    int a[MAX];
    int b[MAX];
    int m,n,index;

    m = tableFill(a, MAX);
    n = tableFill(b, MAX);

    tablePrint(a,b,n,m);
    index = tableDiff(a,b,m,n);

    if(index==-1)
        printf("Index is the same");
    else
        printf("Index is the different");

    return 0;
}

// read values from stdin into array up to 'max' values
int tableFill(int a[], int max) {

    int r;              // input from scanf
    int next;           // next input value
    int cnt = 0;        // count of values read
    int *ptr;           //pointer
    printf("Enter the numbers! \n");

    while ((r=scanf("%i", &next)) == 1 && next != SENTINEL)
    {
        if (r == 0) //invalid input data
        {
            printf("Nonnumeric data entered. Please enter a number. \n");
            while (getchar()!= '\n');  // flush invalid data
        }
        else
            *ptr++=cnt;
    } 

    if(r==1)   //another value was read but the array is full
        printf("Error - too many values. Array size %i.\n", max);

    return ptr-a; //(ptrb - b) should return the same value
}

int tableDiff (const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m)
{
    const int *ptra = a;        //start for 1st array
    const int *ptrb = b;        //start for 2nd array
    const int *endptra = a+m;   //end for 1st array
    const int *endptrb = b+n;   //end for 2nd array

    while(ptra<endptra && ptrb<endptrb && *ptra==*ptrb)
    {
        ptra++;
        ptrb++;
    }
    if( ptra==endptra && ptrb==endptrb)
    {
        return -1;
    }   
    else
        return ptra -a;   //(ptrb - b) should return the same value
}

//print all elements in array.
void tablePrint (const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m)
{
    int i;  //varriable to print
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%d ", a[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

> Here is my newer version:

The program now continues to work until reaches second sentinel (works correctly).

```
/*
* A simple program to sort numbers in the correct order                             
*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10 //max elements in array
#define SENTINEL -999 //indicate the end of valid input

int main () {
    // read values from stdin into array up to 'max' values
    int tableFill(int a[], int max);
    //compare two arrays and returns the first subscript they differ
    int tableDiff (const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m);
    //print all elements in array
    void tablePrint (const int a[], int n);

    int a[MAX];
    int b[MAX];
    int m,n,index;

    m = tableFill(a, MAX);
    n = tableFill(b, MAX);

    tablePrint(a,m);
    tablePrint(b,n);
    index = tableDiff(a,b,m,n);

    if(index==-1)
        printf("-1. Arrays are the same.");
    else
        printf ("\n The arrays differ at index '%d'.\n", index);

    return 0;
}

// read values from stdin into array up to 'max' values
int tableFill(int a[], int max) {

    int r;              // input from scanf
    int next;           // next input value
    int cnt = 0;        // count of values read 
    int *ptr = a;       //pointer
    printf("Enter the numbers! \n");

    while ((r=scanf("%i", &next))==0  || (next != SENTINEL))
    {
        if (r == 0) //invalid input data
        {
            printf("Nonnumeric data entered. Please enter a number. \n");
            while (getchar()!= '\n');  // flush invalid data
        }
        else if (cnt == max)   //another value was read but the array is full
            printf("Error - too many values. Array size %i.\n", max);
        else {
            *ptr++ = next; 
            ++cnt;  
        }
    } 

    return ptr-a; //(ptrb - b) should return the same value
}

//compare two arrays and returns the first subscript they differ
int tableDiff (const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m)
{
    const int *ptra = a;        //start for 1st array
    const int *ptrb = b;        //start for 2nd array
    const int *endptra = a+m;   //end for 1st array
    const int *endptrb = b+n;   //end for 2nd array

    while(ptra<endptra && ptrb<endptrb && *ptra==*ptrb)
    {
        ptra++;
        ptrb++;
    }
    if( ptra==endptra && ptrb==endptrb)
    {
        return -1;
    }   
    else
        return ptra -a;   //(ptrb - b) should return the same value
}

//print all elements in array
void tablePrint (const int a[], int n)
{
    int i; //loop counter
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%d ", a[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: `max != SENTINEL` is that meant to be `n != SENTINEL`?

Comment: I do not have variable "n" in tableFill function, but I changed it into **next != SENTINEL**. It would make more sense that way, since I want to check the "next" value for sentinel.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo. Meant `next` not `n`.

Comment: at `tableFill` : `int *ptr;` --> `int *ptr = a;`,  `else *ptr++=cnt;` --> `else { *ptr++ = next; ++cnt;}` and Add check `cnt < max`. Also `if (r == 0)` Never true : already `r == 1`

Comment: Now it works till the end! Can you explain me the difference between **int *ptr;** --> **int *ptr = a;**?

Comment: Pointer must point to a specific object. :-)

Comment: The tableFill function I copied from old assignment works in other program.  When I input nonnumeric data - it actually says so - **if (r == 0)**. 
But here **if (r == 0)** just doesn't work (the new function is very similar to function from other program). And why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues in your logic. The first of which in

```
while ((r=scanf("%i", &next)) == 1 && next != SENTINEL)
```

prevents the remainder of the code within the loop from ever executing in the event a non-numeric value is entered. If `r != 1`, you exit the loop, not process further within it.

While not an error, function prototypes within `main` only works when the functions exclusively *do not* rely on each other. They know nothing about one another during execution. Better to move the prototypes above `main`.

The remainder of your logic was somewhat difficult to follow and overly complicated. When you are looking for a difference within two arrays, you only need iterate over common elements. If they have differing number of elements, you know they differ by definition starting at the first unique element. So you can whittle down your comparison code quite a bit. Something like the following is fine:

```
/* check if array 'a' and 'b' are the same, else return index
 * of first difference, otherwise return -1 for equal arrays.
 */
int tablediff (const int *a, const int *b, int sza, int szb)
{
    int i, lim = sza < szb ? sza : szb; /* limit search to common elements */

    for (i = 0; i < lim; i++)   /* for each common element check */
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return i;

    if (sza != szb)             /* if size differs, arrays differ */
        return lim;

    return -1;                  /* otherwise equal */
}
```

You can avoid the use of a `SENTINEL` just by proper bounds checking. Further, while you are free to create a `arrayprint` function that prints 2 arrays, it is far better to create a function that prints a single array and call it twice.

Putting those pieces together, and noting you do not use anything from `stdlib.h`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10 //max elements in array

int tablefill(int *a, int max);
int tablediff (const int *a, const int *b, int sza, int szb);
void tableprn (const int *a, int sza);

int main (void) {

    int a[MAX];
    int b[MAX];
    int idx, sza, szb;

    sza = tablefill (a, MAX);
    szb = tablefill (b, MAX);

    tableprn (a, sza);
    tableprn (b, szb);

    if ((idx = tablediff (a, b, sza, szb)) == -1)
        printf ("\n the arrays are the same.\n\n");
    else
        printf ("\n the arrays differ at index '%d'\n\n", idx);

    return 0;
}

/* read values from stdin into array up to 'max' values */
int tablefill (int *a, int max)
{
    int idx = 0, tmp;
    while (idx < max && scanf (" %d", &tmp) == 1)
        a[idx++] = tmp;

    return idx;
}

/* check if array 'a' and 'b' are the same, else return index
 * of first difference, otherwise return -1 for equal arrays.
 */
int tablediff (const int *a, const int *b, int sza, int szb)
{
    int i, lim = sza < szb ? sza : szb;
    for (i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return i;

    if (sza != szb)
        return lim;

    return -1;
}

/* print all elements in array. */
void tableprn (const int *a, int sz)
{
    int i;  //varriable to print
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf (" %d", a[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

**Example Equal**

```
$ /bin/arraycmp <../dat/20intsame.txt
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495

 the arrays are the same.
```

**Example Differ**

```
$ ./bin/arraycmp <../dat/20intdif.txt
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1494

 the arrays differ at index '9'
```

**Providing Prompts for Input**

When taking user input, it is a good idea to proving meaningful prompts as well so the user isn't left looking at a blinking cursor wondering if the program has hung, or what is going on. So in addition to the logic above, you would want to add simple prompting that explains what the program needs and how to provide the input. Something simple will do:

```
    printf ("\nenter a max of 10 integers below 'ctrl+d` to end.\n");
    sza = tablefill (a, MAX);
    printf ("enter a max of 10 integers below 'ctrl+d` to end.\n");
    szb = tablefill (b, MAX);

    printf ("\nthe arrays entered are:\n\n");
    tableprn (a, sza);
    tableprn (b, szb);
```

(*note:* to generate a manual `EOF` on windoze, the key combination is <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd>)

So for entering less than 10 integers for each array you could do something like:

```
$ ./bin/arraycmp

enter a max of 10 integers below 'ctrl+d` to end.
10 12 14 16 17
enter a max of 10 integers below 'ctrl+d` to end.
10 12 14 15 17

the arrays entered are:

 10 12 14 16 17
 10 12 14 15 17

 the arrays differ at index '3'
```

Look over the example and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: My C class teacher is pretty old and she uses exactly the same material that she taught decades ago.

So she wants function prototypes withing the main(), otherwise deduction grade. I guess it results into

 tablePrint(a,m);
 tablePrint(b,n);

into table print with 4 variables because of it. Otherwise it gives me an error.

Not sure about the sentinel, the assignment tell me to do so (which comes with diskette). I guess the structure code is very obsolete for modern C - but that's what my teacher tell me to do.

The logic however is my personal problem :-) I would try to fix it.

Comment: You can move all of the functions inside `main` as long as they don' depend on each other (or you can order them below `main` so any one that is dependent upon another is declared first.) If that's the way she wants it, then that's the way she gets it. If you have any additional questions, let me know, I'm happy to help further. If you must use a `SENTINEL`, that's fine as well, but it poses the potential for conflict if one of your array values is `-999`.

Comment: Logic found instead of **== 1** I put back **!= EOF**.
Now when nonnumeric data is entered, it says so.

Comment: Yep, that will work! Sorry I didn't snap to that being a critical part of your assignment, I should have caught that.

Comment: Hey. I like your answers.  But how scanf read the second line of 20intsame.txt. Because every time you call tablefill. the idx will be reset to 0. There is no seek. How second time call tablefill will assign the value to int b[];

Comment: @Mark. Yes, that is because you are passing two different arrays `a` & `b`. The function simply fills an array, so with each individual array filled, you will want to start filling at index `0`. If you look at both calls, `sza = tablefill (a, MAX);` and `szb = tablefill (b, MAX);`, that should make it clear that `a` and `b` are filled separately and neither depend on the other.